# shell script to check if a particular URL is hung by logging into it

Tags: shell, unix, url, authentication

We have certain sets of clusters URL and sometimes they go to hung state. URL will open but wont allow you to login. Only way to make sure that its in hung state is by manually logging into each URL and see which one is throwing invalid password message.
So instead of doing it manually I wanted to write a shell script for checking it and sending out the mail if its hung.
We already have a script that checks if the URL is up. It just checks the http mesaage. But i want something which can pass the login credentials and let us know if its throwing invalid username password message. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If your login form is very simple(a post request).You can use `curl` to post your login form and `grep` the output's error message part.To see if your URL is working well with login event.